# Store data as JSON in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a digital-card generator app in node.js. In this I want to store the card data as JSON in the MongoDB database. I am using mongoose ODM. but I think mongoose does not support the data-type of Json or object.

The card schema:

```
const digitalCardSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    data: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: MongoDB stores data as documents. Documents have a JSON like structure, and also has additional data types like Date, ObjectId, etc.

Comment: I am aware of that but I want specifically `data` field in the above schema as JSON

Comment: You can store it as an object with properties and values like in a JSON.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this option - there is a ***Mixed schema type***

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed